# CI configuration will be hosted in a different project within GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I created a group "mygroup"
Created a repository "myrepository"

Add patch .gitlab-ci.yml@mygroup/myrepository as documented - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#custom-ci-configuration-path
but gitlab ci does not see this file from another repository.

Maybe we should do something else?

Comment: Why do you need `.gitlab-ci.yml` in a different repository?

Comment: The link you provided seems to be broken, BTW

Comment: I'm sorry.
Custom CI configuration path - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#custom-ci-configuration-path

Comment: @Mureinik The project is assembled by the support team and not by the developer.

Comment: Do you have `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in that project? Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: @Mureinik That's just it, I don't get any error.

Comment: Gitlab version < 12.6?

Comment: The problem has been solved. If you commit to a CI branch, the assembly is triggered. But there are no buttons to start the build process.

Comment: @Mureinik, the real question is why would one want to have .gitlab-ci.yml, a "DevOPS" file, in a project alongside the sources?

Comment: @EricMORAND I'd hardly call `gitlab-ci.yml` a "DevOps file". It's a configuration file for your CI pipeline. It defined how your code is built, tested and deployed. Where else would you keep it if not next to your source files?

Comment: @Mureinik, I think that CI is not the responsibility of the developers. Writing tests is. But how and when those tests are executed is the responsibility of the CI strategy. Same thing with build scripts. Devs are expected to write them but when and how they will be executed is none of their responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the same problem.

You should change `mygroup` and `myrepository` visibility to `internal` or `public`.

[change group visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz9Ix.png)

[change repository visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJYDe.png)